# GraphQL Query Error - Unexpected end of JSON input (Laravel - rebing / graphql-laravel)

Tags: php, json, laravel, graphql, laravel-10

I'm currently working on a GraphQL query that fetches a large dataset from my server. However, I'm encountering an "unexpected end of JSON input" error. This issue seems to be related to the size of the dataset. The query works fine with smaller datasets, but as the data grows, the error occurs. Basically the query is when I am exporting large number of products from my portal. Please check the attached image for reference.

- Package I am using: rebing/graphql-laravel (https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel)
- Version of package: 8.6
- Laravel version: 10.33.0
- PHP version: 8.1

To solve this issue I have already tried below options:

- Increased the size of memory limit
- Implemented whole export code using job and chunk.
- Restarted server and all artisan commands to clear cache and everything

Please suggest me the solution for it.

[image]

Comment: check if you have any error inside laravel log, if not then another possible reason would be the max content limit your webserver impose which then truncate the exceeding characters.  e.i. nginx has 1MB default size limit.  that error you're getting normally occurs when you're expecting a json, but the the data receive is not a json (like errors message) or invalid json format  which can happen if the response is truncated.

Comment: Doesn't look like a GraphQL issue per se, looks like data is being truncated while being returned to the resolver. Your query only returns a url and a typename both of which are small. @silver's comment is very helpful.

Comment: No it is not just returning the url, I have just fetched the url parameter, it has many parameters.